# Web app code generator

Tags: sql, code-generation, parent-child

I have a request to create a web application on a a public web site that would display data from about 5 tables in mySQL.  I would like to display parent/child relationships.

Is there a product that I could use to generate code to do this?  I was thinking PHP would be good to use.

Comment: SQL Maestro seems like a good product.  http://www.sqlmaestro.com

Also I am looking at MS Dynamic Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Iron Speed](http://www.ironspeed.com/) is easy to use, looks awesome, is free for five tables and claims to work with MySQL.

Comment: This looks like a good option but might be overkill for what we are trying to do.  It looks like it is free for up to 15 tables.